# EntityNotFoundException: deleted entity passed to persist

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernateexception

I try to delete one row in my table:

My page:

```
        <p:dataTable id="table" styleClass="tableHistory" value="#{patientCardMB.history}" var="history" paginator="true" rows="15" rowKey="#{history.id}" selection="#{patientCardMB.patientCard}" selectionMode="single"  >

            <f:facet name="header">
                Historia
            </f:facet>

            <p:column headerText="#{msg.date}">
                <h:outputText id="historyText" value="#{history.dateVisit}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{tableBean.onRowSelect()}" update=":form:table" />
            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton id="viewButton" value="#{msg.info}" icon="ui-icon-search"  
                                 update=":form:display" oncomplete="userDialog.show()" disabled="#{tableBean.flag}"/>
                <p:commandButton action="#{patientCardMB.createStart()}" value="#{msg.add}" icon="ui-icon-plus" />
                <p:commandButton action="#{patientCardMB.editStart()}" value="#{msg.edit}" disabled="#{tableBean.flag}" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-pencil"/>
                <p:commandButton value="#{msg.delete}" onclick="confirmation.show()" type="button" disabled="#{tableBean.flag}" icon="ui-icon-close"/>
                <p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialog" message="Jesteś pewien, że chcesz usunąć wybrany wpis?"  
                                 header="Potwierdzenie usunięcia" severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmation"> 
                    <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="Tak" oncomplete="confirmation.hide()"
                                     action="#{patientCardMB.delete()}" />
                    <p:commandButton id="decline" value="Nie" onclick="confirmation.hide()" type="button" /> 
                </p:confirmDialog>
            </f:facet>
        </p:dataTable>
```

I do a method `patientCardMB.delete()` :

```
public String delete() {
    System.out.println(patientCard);
    try {
        patientCardDao.delete(patientCard);
    } catch (EJBException e) {
        sendErrorMessageToUser("Błąd usuwania wpisu");
    }
    sendInfoMessageToUser("Wpis usunięty");
    return "delete";
}
```

patientCardDAo.delete:

```
@Override
public void delete(PatientCard patientCard) {
    PatientCard toRemoved = em.merge(patientCard);
    em.remove(toRemoved);
}
```

Entity PatientCard:

```
public class PatientCard implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "dateVisit")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateVisit;
    @Size(max = 4000)
    @Column(name = "diagnosis")
    private String diagnosis;
    @Size(max = 250)
    @Column(name = "medications")
    private String medications;
    @JoinColumn(name = "patient_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private User patientId;
    @JoinColumn(name = "doctor_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private User doctorId;
```

When i try delete i have this error:

> WARNING: DTX5014: Caught exception in beforeCompletion() callback:
>   javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: deleted entity passed to
>   persist: [pl.ePrzychodnia.model.PatientCard#]   at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:621)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$1.beforeCompletion(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:532)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:435)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:855)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5136)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4901)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2045)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1994)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:222)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:89)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy203.delete(Unknown Source)   at
>   pl.ePrzychodnia.mb.PatientCardMB.delete(PatientCardMB.java:102)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   javax.el.BeanELResolver.invokeMethod(BeanELResolver.java:779)     at
>   javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:528)   at
>   javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:257)     at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:248)  at
>   com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
>     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1093)  at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>
> WARNING: EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on
>   EJB PatientCardDao, method: public void
>   pl.ePrzychodnia.dao.PatientCardDao.delete(pl.ePrzychodnia.model.PatientCard)
>   WARNING: javax.ejb.EJBException: Transaction aborted  at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5142)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4901)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2045)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1994)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:222)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:89)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy203.delete(Unknown Source)   at
>   pl.ePrzychodnia.mb.PatientCardMB.delete(PatientCardMB.java:102)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   javax.el.BeanELResolver.invokeMethod(BeanELResolver.java:779)     at
>   javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:528)   at
>   javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:257)     at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:248)  at
>   com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
>     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1093)  at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by:
>   javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction marked for rollback.
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:473)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:855)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5136)
>     ... 51 more Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException:
>   deleted entity passed to persist:
>   [pl.ePrzychodnia.model.PatientCard#]    at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:621)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$1.beforeCompletion(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:532)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:435)
>     ... 53 more

I don't now why i have this error. Earlier I did delete a similar entity, and all work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing process and update attribute in

```
 <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="Tak" oncomplete="confirmation.hide()"
                                 action="#{patientCardMB.delete()}" process="@parent" update="@form" />
```

Comment: Help someone in my problem?